# How add Items to Tableview Javafx 8 without Creating Class

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm learning JavaFX 8 and working on Tableview.
I know we can add data to table view by using following steps.

```
ObservableList<PersonCode> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PersonCode("Jacob", "Smith"),
            new PersonCode("Isabella", "Johnson"),
            new PersonCode("Ethan", "Williams"),
            new PersonCode("Emma", "Jones"),
            new PersonCode("Michael", "Brown")
        );
```

Then set Column cellValueFactory

```
TableColumn<PersonCode, String> firstName = new TableColumn<PersonCode, String>("First Name");
firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PersonCode, String>("aName"));

TableColumn<PersonCode, String> lastName = new TableColumn<PersonCode, String>("Last Name");
lastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PersonCode, String>("aNameLast"));
```

and then `table.setItems(data);`

**But my question is**, can we add data to table's column without creating another class? As in my previous example I have created `PersonCode` class. But I want to add following data to tableview.

```
ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Good","Luck","Bad");
```

As I was reading [Tableview Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJADAHAH) there I found this line.

> When you create a table in a JavaFX application, **it is a best practice
>   to implement a class that defines the data model** and provides methods
>   and fields to further work with the table. Example 13-3 creates the
>   Person class to define data in an address book.

So I'm expecting we can add data without creating a separate class. How? any idea?

Comment: By using a existing class...

Comment: @fabian how? can you give an example